# How to serialize JSON from Form (multipart/form-data) to list?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

When I try to post multipart/form-data with my file and JSON, then lists are empty in model, but Alias, WorkerName and File are correctly serialized.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("add")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public async Task<JobAddDto> Add([FromForm] JobInputInternalDto model)
{
    var form = Request.Form;
    //do stuff with model
}
```

[image]

In Request.Form those values are correctly sent:
[image]

How can I serialize data from form to lists in my model?

I have my JobInputInternalDto written as:

```
public class JobInputDto
{
    public string Alias { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string WorkerName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public IEnumerable<ParameterDto> Parameters { get; set; } = new List<ParameterDto>();
    public IEnumerable<WorkflowOptionsDto> Workflow { get; set; } = new List<WorkflowOptionsDto>();
}

public class JobInputInternalDto : JobInputDto
{
    public IFormFile? Payload { get; set; } = null;
}
```

With ParameterDto as:

```
public class ParameterDto
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

And WorkflowOptionsDto as:

```
public class WorkflowOptionsDto
{
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string WorkerName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? WorkerVersion { get; set; } = null;

    public IEnumerable<ParameterDto> Parameters { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<ParameterDto>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What i can guess by your Request.Form image is that you've sent the Parameters data with Json format like:

```
{ Order: 0, Name: "Test Name 0", Value: "Test Value 0" }
```

But since you're using

```
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
```

As such, C# expects the model to be form formatted, and therefore a list of objects should have the following format:

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the following image, using form format, C# is able to bind the data properly:

[image]